# how i can get parts of web pages by php

Tags: php

i want make a news site gets its content from other news sites,
open the rss feed and feach url and open the html dom of the page then
get just the text of the news
i think i have to use the DOMDocument class of the php?

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Following links in an RSS feed to grab the full article and then republishing it? You are running towards copyright infringement there. I recommend backing off.

Comment: This is strictly prohibited and could cause a lot of legal issues, so watch out with it.

If you still want to continue take a look at: SimpleXML & XPath

Comment: in addition to the stealing of other peoples content mentioned above, if you are doing this everytime a user requests your page your site will feel extremely slow.

Comment: you can receive a duplicate content penalty if you copy full articles. If you only copy a summary, you might fly under the radar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feeds are XML. To get the links here I would use [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php). To load the page you can use [cURL](http://de.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php) or [HttpRequest](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.httprequest-send.php).

To analyse the returned code I would use DOMDocument, too! Alternatively you could use [simpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).